# Entity Framework Navigable Property Not Set to Instance of Object?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following query:

```
 Dim queryStudent = (From p In dbContext.Residents _
                     Where p.people_code_id = people_id _
                     Where p.year = year _
                     Where p.semester = semester _
                     Join b In dbContext.Buildings On p.building Equals b.id _
                     Join r In dbContext.Rooms On p.room Equals r.id
                     Select p, b, r)
```

I then attempt to pull the building and room for that individual like so:

```
room = queryStudent.FirstOrDefault.r.id
building = queryStudent.FirstOrDefault.b.id
```

But I receive an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.

I tried doing something like

```
 If IsNothing(queryStudent.FirstOrDefault.r.id) Then  
     room = ""
 Else     
     room = queryStudent.FirstOrDefault.r.id
 End If
```

But that still generates the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if r is nothing instead of the id of r.

```
 If IsNothing(queryStudent.FirstOrDefault.r) Then   
     room = "" 
 Else      
     room = queryStudent.FirstOrDefault.r.id 
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect queryStudent.FirstOrDefault is null. If you try to access a property of a null object, you get that exception. Try this approach:

```
If IsNothing(queryStudent.FirstOrDefault) Then  
     room = ""
Else If IsNothing(queryStudent.First.r) Then
    room = ""
Else     
     room = queryStudent.FirstOrDefault.r.id
End If
```

In each case, you are checking that the object you are about to access is not null.